# HsqlDB embedded table issue with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hsqldb

Hi i'm using `HSQLDB` embedded with my spring boot application.

`application.properties`

```
# Database
db.driver: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
db.url: jdbc:hsqldb:db/HSQL_DB/app;shutdown=true
db.username: sa
db.password: sa

# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql: true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate
entitymanager.packagesToScan: com.gvj.entity
```

`configuration`

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Value("${db.driver}")
    private String DB_DRIVER;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String DB_PASSWORD;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String DB_URL;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String DB_USERNAME;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String HIBERNATE_DIALECT;

    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;

    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO;

    @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
    private String ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(DB_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

`app.script`

```
SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB3ABA95207E
SET DATABASE GC 0
SET DATABASE DEFAULT RESULT MEMORY ROWS 0
SET DATABASE EVENT LOG LEVEL 0
SET DATABASE SQL NAMES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL REFERENCES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL SIZE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TYPES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC DELETE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC UPDATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONCAT NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL UNIQUE NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONVERT TRUNCATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL LONGVAR IS LOB FALSE
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS
SET DATABASE DEFAULT ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION ROLLBACK ON DEADLOCK TRUE
SET DATABASE TEXT TABLE DEFAULTS ''
SET FILES WRITE DELAY 500 MILLIS
SET FILES BACKUP INCREMENT TRUE
SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000
SET FILES CACHE ROWS 50000
SET FILES SCALE 8
SET FILES LOB SCALE 32
SET FILES DEFRAG 0
SET FILES NIO TRUE
SET FILES NIO SIZE 256
SET FILES LOG TRUE
SET FILES LOG SIZE 50
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD DIGEST 'c12e01f2a13ff5587e1e9e4aedb8242d'
ALTER USER SA SET LOCAL TRUE
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
CREATE TEXT TABLE PUBLIC.USER_ACCOUNT(ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,USER_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,PASSWORD VARCHAR(20)NOT NULL)
CREATE TEXT TABLE PUBLIC.IP_CONFIG(ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,IP_ADDRESS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)
ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 1
SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
SET TABLE PUBLIC.USER_ACCOUNT SOURCE 'user_account'
SET TABLE PUBLIC.IP_CONFIG SOURCE 'ip_config'
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TIME_STAMP TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CARDINAL_NUMBER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_DATA TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_IDENTIFIER TO PUBLIC
GRANT DBA TO SA
SET SCHEMA SYSTEM_LOBS
INSERT INTO BLOCKS VALUES(0,2147483647,0)
```

I have specified the text table inside app.script file and when i run the application the app.script file reset to default and the text table just automatically overwritten. How do i prevent that.

Comment: Where/how is the script executed? Also you are using Spring Boot but why aren't you using Spring Boot? You are trying very hard to work around it by your manual configuration (Spring Boot already configures a datasource for you).

Comment: Ok needed to check the documentation. The script file contains all the executed queries and is basically used to restore the state of your db. As you are including it, it will be run each time you start the application. I doubt you really want a script file or simple a sql file with just some create table statements (for which you either could use a `schema.sql` used by Spring Boot or more elaborate somethingl ike flyway).

Comment: @M.Deinum  what you mean my where/how the script executed.